# disabling UIButton throws an error

Tags: uibutton, swift3

I have two UIButtons, I want one button when pressed, to disable the other button.

I have tried code from different posters but have been unable to get one UIButton to disable the other UIButton.

I am able to setTitleColor and disable using Sender but that won't work for the other button.

Here is some partial code of the IF/Else statement, but it should be enough for the experienced coder.

This code builds successfully but throws an exception at the last line shown when run.  Fatal Error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.  Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_I...

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var buttonAdd: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var buttonEdit: UIButton!

@IBAction func buttonAdd(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    if (sender.currentTitle == "Add")
    {

        sender.setTitle("Save", for:UIControlState.normal)
        sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for:UIControlState.normal)

        buttonEdit.isEnabled = false  FAILS ON THIS LINE
```

Comment: Your storyboard has no outlet to `buttonEdit`.

Comment: OK so how to I accomplish adding an outlet to the storyboard ?  Please be specific with code.

Comment: There is no code involved. Please do not tell me how to answer.

Comment: Since I didn't know how to install the outlet from the storyboard, I manually installed (typed in) the outlet code you see in the View Controller class. But obviously some missing code was required someplace else in order for it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This generally happens when the outlet from your storyboard to your code is messed up. Go to storyboard, right click on the yellow ViewController symbol and you will see a warning. You should delete the entry with the warning by clicking on the 'x' and recreate a new outlet form storyboard to your code.

[image]

Comment: In the View Controller Scene ...rt. Clicking on the yellow View Controller pops open the View Controller box and both of my buttons, buttonAdd and buttonEdit appear under Outlets. There is no yellow warning on either button, hence there is no X to click.

Comment: I figured it out, from the View Controller box drag a blue line to its corresponding button on the storyboard. Thx nitinsh99

Comment: Since i didnt install the outlet from the storyboard, because I didnt know how, I had manually installed the outlet code you see in the View Controller class.  But obviously missing code required someplace else.